# How to get data from an array of specific paths in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with dates now, and I structured the database like this:

```
database[userId][work][year][month][date]
```

So if I want to get the working hours of an user, on a specific date, I call:

```
const getWorkData = (userId, year, month, date, callback) => {
    usersRef.child(`${userId}/work/${year}/${month}/${date}`).on("value", snap =>
        callback(snap.val())
    )
}
```

If I need just one date's data, this function works perfectly. But I want to show the user a whole week of data. Here comes the problem.

I have two possible solutions, but neither of them are practical.

```js
//loop through an array of the week's dates

const weeksDates = [
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 12},
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 13},
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 14},
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 15},
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 16},
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 17},
  {year: 2018, month: 11, date: 18},
];

const userId = "userId";
const getWorkData = (userId, year, month, date, callback) => {
    usersRef.child(`${userId}/work/${year}/${month}/${date}`).on("value", snap =>
        callback(snap.val())
    )
}

//loop through the dates, and fetch data at each date

const getWorkDataOfWeek = (userId, weeksDates) => {
  const data = [];
  const pushToData = value => data.push(value)
  weeksDates.forEach(dateObj => {
    const { year, month, date } = dateObj;
    getWorkData(userId, year, month, date, pushToData)
  })
}

//fetch the whole database, and filter it

const getWorkDataOfWeek = (userId, weeksDates, callback) => {
  usersRef.child(userId).on("value", snap => {
    const workData = snap.val();
    const data = weeksDates.map(dateObj => {
      const { year, month, date } = dateObj;
      return workData[year][month][date];
    })
    callback(data)
  })
}
```

The problem with the first method is that it creates too much requests. The problem with the second is that it requests too large amount of data. Is there a solution for firebase which is similar to the first except that it just requests once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principle of an object database like Firebase is to be able to arrange the data the way you want and will need it for futur use.  This prevent heavy CPU loads when retrieving data and so on, you achieve this by doing denormalization.  This meanss you anticipate how you would need the data back and write it has so.  So you need data by week and by date, write the data has week and date in the first place.

Something like this:

/UID/year/month/date
/UID/year/week/date . ( you should already know that week is 12, 13 ...)

With Firebase it's really easy to save data on multiple path at once, you use multi paths updates.

Articles about denormalization: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Articles about multi path updates: https://medium.com/@danbroadbent/firebase-multi-path-updates-updating-denormalized-data-in-multiple-locations-b433565fd8a5

P.S. I would also add that it seems to me that you want to read that data only when you need it so use once instead of on.